# Run a script when mouse is idle

Tags: mouse, xdotool

I want to run a command like `xdotool 9999 0` after the mouse has been idle for some time. The goal is to get the mouse out of the way - I like to use my keyboard only, and the mouse often causes annoyances like highlighting links as I scroll and triggering tooltips. Note that I want this to happen after *mouse* inactivity only - so keyboard activity should be disregarded.

I already use `unclutter` which visually hides the pointer. Unfortunately the pointer seems active even when hidden, and can trigger mouseover events. It seems like there is no feature in `unclutter` to run a custom command or script instead.

Tools like `xprintidle` do not distinguish keyboard vs. mouse idle. If there is a way to make them differentiate them, it would solve my problem.

How can I run my command after the mouse has not been moved for a certain amount of time (eg. 5 minutes)?

Answer (score 1):

I have made a patch that solves the hidden-mouse-still-hovering-stuff problem, It's [available on my github](https://github.com/iacobucci/unclutter-xfixes-tooltip)!